# Cannot get XmlHttpRequest to work with CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest

I made a small application that gets data from a weighing scale over rs232, and that returns that data with a builtin web server, on an URL like `http://localhost:51111/Scale1?min=1.5&max=420` . The params are to set some config data to the scale.

Now I need to get the data in a web page, served from an IIS server on a central machine. There is a CORS issue here, but my firefox seems to support CORS:

```
var supportsCORS = (new XMLHttpRequest()).withCredentials !== undefined;
```

returns True.

Using the info found on several fora and JS books, I made this JS code:

```
    function httpGetAsync() {
        var theUrl = 'http://localhost:51111/Scale1?min=1.5&max=420';
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                $('#value').text('state: ' + req.readyState + ', status: ' + req.status + ', text: ' + req.responseText);
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
        req.send(null);
        return;
    }
```

The web page has extra HTTP headers to allow Cross Origin Request Scripting (CORS):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:51111
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
```

Using Fiddler and the Firefox debugger (F12) I can see that the JS is indeed sending a request to the local application listening to port 51111, on that app I can see that the min/max data is received correctly, and the app responses with status 200, and some data in the body, this is the raw response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 4
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 15 Aug 2017 14:36:50 GMT

1.15
```

Looking cool, but:

My problem is that the above JS does not have the body content: req.status is zero 0, not 200, and req.responseText is the empty string instead of the "1.15" .

I tried Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: The `http://localhost:51111` server needs to be configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and any other necessary `Access-Control-Allow-*` response headers. From your question it’s not clear where or how you’re setting those, but the response cited in the question doesn’t show them being received as response headers, so it seems you must not have the `http://localhost:51111` server configured to send them

Comment: @sideshowbarker You were right! The extra header needs to be in the response of the second server. I am reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS to get to understand this. If you would post your comment as a solution, I would happily accept.

Comment: @sideshowbarker As you are listed as a contributor to that mozilla page, you might be the right person to tell some more about CORS to understand why the extra headers need to be in the response of that second server and not in that of the first server.

Comment: @sideshowbarker OK, I found some Helpful background info in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480612/security-concerns-about-cors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http://localhost:51111` server needs to be configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and any other necessary `Access-Control-Allow-*` response headers. That’s because it’s the server to which the frontend JS code is sending the request.

The response cited in the question doesn’t show those being received as response headers, so it seems you must not have the `http://localhost:51111` server configured to send them.

By default browsers won’t allow your frontend JS code to access the response from a cross-origin request—unless a server opts-in to allowing it. And the way the servers opt-in to allowing cross-origin requests is by sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in responses.

All the actual enforcement of the CORS protocol is done by browsers. So the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what servers use to communicate with browsers; servers use it for telling browsers which origins they want browsers to expose responses from this server to.

So that’s why in your case the `http://localhost:51111` server is the one you need to configure to send the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.