# ReactJs Axios response status code always 0

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm sending requests to server side using ReactJs(17.0.2) and Axios (0.27.2). I use axios intercepters in some common situations.

```
 axiosApiInstance = axios.create();
  axiosApiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      config.headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
          "token"
        )}`,
        "Accept-Language": "tr",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      };
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        /////
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

I'm using spring boot in the backend and using @CrossOrigin on controller tops.

Question:

The error.response.status part is always 0. But I am seeing 401 error on the network. What I want to do is trigger a function when error.response.status=== 401. When I researched for this, I couldn't find a clear solution. The same problem persisted when I got the latest version of Axios. How do I get the error.response.status value to be different from 0?

Or should I use another library instead of axios?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are response headers that come from the server. They do not belong in your request and in general will more than likely result in errors like _"Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"_.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to be configured to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Beause axios used XMLHttpRequest call request.If have err xhr.js alway call "request.onerror" not call "request.onerror"
[Cannot get XmlHttpRequest to work with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695466/cannot-get-xmlhttprequest-to-work-with-cors)

Answer (score -1):

The http library would not matter in this case. A `status 0` indicates no response from the server. Consider this **Axios interceptor hook** and [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-express-axios-interceptor-handling-status-codes-ktnfxu):

`useInterceptor.js`

```
import axios from "axios";

const useAxiosInterceptor = () => {
  axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => req);

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (err) => {
      if (err?.response?.status != null) {
        console.log(`Response status: ${err.response.status}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`No response, request status = `, err.request.status);
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  );

  return null;
};

export default useAxiosInterceptor;
```

If the server does not respond, it can't give you a status. With Axios interceptor, the `status 0` exists on `err.request.status` instead of `err.response.status`. Check out [Handling Errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors) and [Interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) which highlight this.